# Tail-recursive function to count all numbers larger than average in an array

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

I need to make a function that calculates the average and **return the number of values larger than the average**. For example, passing an array of {4, 5, 12, 17} should return 2 (because 12 and 17 are larger than the average 9.5). So far I wrote the function to return the average, but how can I make it count the numbers larger than the average and keep it tail-recursive?

```
int TAvg(int* a, int size, int acc=0, int num=0){ //acc is the sum so far, num is the number of all elements
if (size == 0){ 
    return (acc / num); 
}
return TAvg(a, size - 1, acc+a[size-1], num+1);}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems you want us to solve your homework.

Comment: By *average*, you seem to have meant *arithmetic mean* specifically.

Comment: Take a look to STL  `<algorithm>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: And try to use `vector` instead C array and pointer. Unless it is a C question instead a C++ question, in such case I would suggest you that update the tags

Comment: "but how can I make it count the numbers larger than the average and keep it tail-recursive?" I don't think you can.

Comment: Two quotes from your question (1) `int TAvg(` (2) `average 9.5`. Don't think they can work together well.

Comment: Can you write a separate tail-recursive function that calculates number of array elements above a given value?

Answer (score 1):

Once your tail-recursive function calculates the average on the final recursion call, and starts unwinding the call stack, as its unwinding the recursive calls it now knows what the average is.

It can now compare the average with each element, as its unwinding all the recursion calls, and increment a counter for each element is above the computed average.

EDIT: I thought of another approach that implements more of a spirit of a tail-recursive design. Have your function return a class:

```
class result {

public:

     int average;
     int counter;

     result(int average, int last_value) : average(average), counter(0)
     {
         if (last_value > average)
             ++counter;
     }

     result(const result &prev_result, int next_value) : average(prev_result.average), counter(prev_result.counter)
     {
         if (next_value > average)
             ++counter;
     }
};
```

Now your tail-recursive function can compute the result by:

1. The initial recursive call (or the last recursive call, depending on one's point of view), would construct `result` by using the first constructor, using the computed average, and the first/last value in the array:

   ```
   return result(TAvg(computed_average_goes_here, *acc));
   ```
2. The remaining tail-recursive calls become:

   ```
   return result( TAvg( /* resursive parameters */), *acc);
   ```

Comment: Exactly, but how do i do that? and where should i place the counter? since it's tail-recursive nothing should be written after the call.

Comment: There is no law that says that "nothing should be written after the call" does not make it tail recursive. You can have your tail-recursive function return a std::pair<int, int>, the average, and the counter, and turn your recursive call into `update(TAvg(...), *acc)`, with `update()` comparing `*acc` with the first value in the pair, and incrementing the second value, and returning the updated pair.

Comment: A tail recursive function **does not** unwind the stack. That's the point of it being tail-recursive. It can be compiled to code that doesn't use call stack at all.